# Pyspark: Error executing Jupyter command while running a file using spark-submit

Tags: pyspark, jupyter-notebook, spark-submit

I am able to run pyspark and run a script on Jupyter notebook.
But when I try to run the file from terminal using spark-submit, getting this error:

*Error executing Jupyter command **file path** [Errno 2] No such file or directory*

Can anyone help me what's wrong with my config?

I'm using Python 2.7 and Spark 1.6

Answer (score 29):

These problem occurs because you have set jupyter to run pyspark script . 
Now you should unset `PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON` variable  command for the same is `$ unset PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON` then try spark-submit again
`./bin/spark-submit examples/src/main/python/streaming/network_wordcount.py localhost 9999`.

Comment: I was using the following in spark-env.sh
export PYSPARK_PYTHON=python3.7
# export PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON=jupyter
# export PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON_OPTS="notebook"

If I want to run Jupyter will have to set the driver and run separately pyspark command. Thanks not spark-submit command.